# Viewport initial-scale bug

Tags: html, css, meta-tags, metatag

When I try to access my site on iphone, it seems that the initial-scale isnt working very well.. The width dont fits the screen and googled many times but nothing seems to solve my problem.. can anyone help me?

metatag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1">
```

css:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    ...
}
```

this is the url http://www.estudiocaju.com.br/homolog/dleve/home/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- iPhone Retina -->

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> 

<!-- iPhone 5 -->

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,width=320.1">
```

Setting Launch Icons / Splash Screens:

```
     <!-- iPhone (Retina) -->

    <link href="imgs/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png"

    sizes="114x114"

    rel="apple-touch-icon">

    <link href="imgs/apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png"

    media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)

    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"

    rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

    <!-- iPhone 5 -->

    <link href="imgs/apple-touch-startup-image-640x1096.png"

    media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px)

    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"

    rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not one of logic or intention or extraneous factors, but simply one of syntax. The separator inside the 'content' part of a 'viewport' should be comma (,) rather than semicolon (;). Your use of semicolons is messing up the browser's parsing of the viewport instruction, most likely causing all the content past the first semicolon to be invisible to the browser.

Comment: @ramon vasconcelos Hope this answer's in time to help you :-(